# Transaction based monitoring service for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, testing, transactions, monitoring, performance-testing

I am looking for a service for my rails application to monitor and alert/notify based on transaction based tests. I already looked at pingdom but it doesn't support uploading files and that's crucial to my use case. what other services i can use to test and monitor my transaction. My use case is as follows:

1. User logs in to their iTunesConnect account via our login form
2. User selects multiple image(s) to upload to iTunesConnect
3. The images get uploaded locally
4. User see the preview screen to preview the images and pass validations
5. Final upload which is through a background service where the images get uploaded to users' iTunesConnect account.

Answer (score 0):

[WDT.io](https://wdt.io) can be used to monitor transactions with an "on-demand timer". At the beginning of your transaction, your code makes an HTTP request to wdt.io, and then again at the end of the transaction. If the second request doesn't come in within  predefined time, you'll get an alert.

I'm not familiar with iTunesConnect, so this may not help. Also, if you have multiple transactions running concurrently, this won't be of help either.